# Error build open rasta castle windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, openrasta

I try to build OpenRasta Castle Windsor.

Firstly, I clone Openrasta Castle [Github Repository](https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-castle-windsor). And I execute `make.bat` from command prompt. But I got these error:

```
D:\Software\dotNET\OpenRasta\openrasta-castle-windsor>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\F
ramework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe build\build.proj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.488]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 18/04/2012 10:46:48.
Project "D:\Software\dotNET\OpenRasta\openrasta-castle-windsor\build\build.proj
" on node 1 (default targets).
D:\Software\dotNET\OpenRasta\openrasta-castle-windsor\build\build.proj(11,75):
error MSB4064: The "CurrentProjectFile" parameter is not supported by the "Init
ializeOpenWrap" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a sett
able public instance property.
D:\Software\dotNET\OpenRasta\openrasta-castle-windsor\build\build.proj(11,5): e
rror MSB4063: The "InitializeOpenWrap" task could not be initialized with its i
nput parameters.
Done Building Project "D:\Software\dotNET\OpenRasta\openrasta-castle-windsor\bu
ild\build.proj" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"D:\Software\dotNET\OpenRasta\openrasta-castle-windsor\build\build.proj" (defau
lt target) (1) ->
(_Initialize target) ->
  D:\Software\dotNET\OpenRasta\openrasta-castle-windsor\build\build.proj(11,75)
: error MSB4064: The "CurrentProjectFile" parameter is not supported by the "In
itializeOpenWrap" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a se
ttable public instance property.
  D:\Software\dotNET\OpenRasta\openrasta-castle-windsor\build\build.proj(11,5):
 error MSB4063: The "InitializeOpenWrap" task could not be initialized with its
 input parameters.

    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.06
```

Thanks in advance.